# Jaccard distance implementation in C

Tags: c, algorithm

Here is my code, why the intersection and union between a letter and an other   always equal to one, I extracted the code from here [jaccard](https://datadryad.org/bitstream/handle/10255/dryad.70383/Smith-Patten_Patten_C_Program.pdf?sequence=1), as I know the Jaccard similarity between two sets A and B it is the ration of cardinality of A ∩ B and A ∪ B , I would like to consider a string as a set of character

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char source[5] = "salam";
    char cible[5] = "Salam";
    int i, in = 0, un = 0;
    float Jaccard = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        un += (source[i] || cible[i]);
        in += (source[i] && cible[i]);
    }

    printf("un :: %d\n", un);
    printf("in :: %d\n", in);

    Jaccard = (float)in / un * 100.0;
    printf("jaccard :: %f\n", Jaccard);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the "doesn't work" part. *How* does it not work? What output did you expect? What output did you get? If you haven't [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet, then please do so. Also please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: `source[i] || cible[i]` is just calculating the logical OR between two ASCII codes, this doesn't really make sense. Same goes for `source[i] && cible[i])` which calculâtes the logical AND.

Comment: @Some programmer dude in this particular case it is quite obvious what does not work

Comment: @PeterJ Yes, but the OP still needs to spell it out. It might be obvious for us in this case, but what if in the next question it *isn't*? Good habits needs to start early.

Comment: i edited it, i mean i expect to get for exemple "a" && "a" == 1 and "a" && "b" == 0

Comment: He thinks that the C natively supports the algebra of sets

Comment: @aslimane Then perhaps you should use *comparison* instead? Because `'a' == 'a'` will be `1`, and `'a' == 'b'` will be `0`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude No - as the result of set "Sel" (OR) set "Salam" shold be set "Salame".

Comment: Apart from all the above mentioned points, your jaccard index might still be wrong because  you are not looking at sets (uniqueness of elements).

Comment: Also, you are only comparing the corresponding elements. But the set remains the same even if shuffled. Perhaps a unique sort and then comparison might yield appropriate results. Comparison still won't be how you are doing now. You will need two separate indices. If you have only alpha numeric characters, just maintain a bit map.

Comment: i will try to simulate the union and intersection of sets using equality comparison

Comment: @aslimane you still didn't tell us what output exactly you expect from your program. Give us some examples of different `source` and `cible`and what output you expect for each of them.

Comment: You see, in the link you pasted, they are operating on the bit map `B`. So there the `||` and `&&` make sense.

Comment: C is not the bast language for it. You should use more high level ones. APL, Matlab, Analitica, R - but on this forum are better specialists

Comment: i need it in c to use it in cython (to do parallel operation with no gil) ,to speed up the process of iterating over a huge lists of string,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You picked up the logic for set intersection and union but you didn't convert the input into the representation they use the logic on.

You can't directly act on the input string. You need to operate on a bit map.

Following logic can help you get a bitmap from a string.

```
uint8_t Bitmap1[256] = {0};
uint8_t Bitmap2[256] = {0};

for (i=0;input1[i];i++){
    Bitmap1[input1[i]] = 1;
}
for (i=0;input2[i];i++){
    Bitmap2[input2[i]] = 1;
}
```

Now you can use the logic to count set union and intersection.

```
in = 0;
un = 0;


for(i=0;i<256;i++){
    in+=Bitmap1[i] && Bitmap2[i];
    un+=Bitmap1[i] || Bitmap2[i];
}

// Rest of the logic
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://ideone.com/wQMm26) with valid result on your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
    un += (source[i] || cible[i]);  // allways true you can replace it with un++
    in += (source[i] && cible[i]);  // allways true you can replace it with in++
```

In the C every value != 0 is true and zero if the false.

So the `source[i] || cible[i]` is always true as source[i] and cible[i] is allways != 0 
same `source[i] && cible[i]` is always true as both sides of the expression are non zero